# Remap arrow keys to another keys with JavaScript on GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I'm trying to set up a TamperMonkey script to reassign the `Right Arrow` key to `F` key.

I tried this code, but so far, nothing happens when I press `F`.

```
    (function(){
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
 // pressed F
  if (e.keyCode == 70 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
  keyCode == 39 // this should trigger the right arrow
  }
}, false);
})();
```

Can someone enlighten me on this, please?

Comment: A couple of things... 1) `keyCode` isn't defined there, i think you mean `e.keyCode`, 2) `==` doesn't modify the value of a variable, `=` can (but not in this case because...) 3) `e.keyCode` is a readonly property and you can't modify it. You might be able to use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

Comment: @Samathingamajig, thanks. I've tried a few different combinations from the page you indicated, but nothing worked.
Can you specify what I should put beside "// this should trigger the right arrow" for it actually to trigger the right arrow?

I'm not a dev, and I'm just trying to fix the system I use to work, using a few JavaScript frameworks. 

I've already achieved to assign keys to some virtual buttons, but this one I'm since a week already, trying alternatives of code, and nothing works.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [the `KeyboardEvent` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) and then [run `dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) on either the entire `document` or a specific element via `document.querySelector`, `document.getElementById`, etc.

Run the snippet below to see this in action.

(BTW, [using `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is depricated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#deprecated) in favor of [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). It still works in major web browsers for backwards compatibility, but it's been officially deprecated in the standards)

(Also make sure your TamperMonkey script is running at `document-end` if you're wanting to run the keyboard event on a custom DOM element)

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') console.log('right arrow pressed');
});

// Your TamperMonkey script starts here
(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.key == 'f' && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
            console.log('f pressed');

            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent
            const keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
                key: 'ArrowRight',
                keyCode: 39,
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                shiftKey: false,
                ctrlKey: false,
                altKey: false,
                metaKey: false,
            });

            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/44190874/12101554
            // replace `document` with a specific element if you want to do a specific
            document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
        }
    });
})();
```

```html
<p>
  press right arrow &amp; f key to see things happen
</p>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('.as-console').innerHTML = ''">clear console</button>
```

However, there isn't a way to disable <kbd>f</kbd> from doing other things on that website. If you want to do this, you can install AutoHotKey [(Wikipedia Link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey), create an AutoHotKey script with this one line:

```
f::^Right
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap

When you start this AHK script, AHK will intercept the key event before (most) programs and modify it.

Comment: You absolutely solved my problem @samathingamajig! I've just deleted the console.log from the script, set one for A as Left Arrow and D as Right Arrow, now I'm fully in control of what I should do, without taking the right hand from the mouse. 
I'm looking to have both hands only on the keyboard since the mouse hurts my wrist and elbow. You are a master, man! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As solved by @samathingamajig, I've just set this script to key `A` interpret `Left Arrow`, and `D` to interpret `Right Arrow`.

It end up like this in my `TamperMonkey`:

```
// MEDIA TO THE RIGHT - ASSIGNED TO *D* KEY
(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.key == 'd' && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
            ;

            const keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
                key: 'ArrowRight',
                keyCode: 39,
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                shiftKey: false,
                ctrlKey: false,
                altKey: false,
                metaKey: false,
            });

            document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
        }
    });
})();


// MEDIA TO THE LEFT - ASSIGNED TO *A* KEY
(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.key == 'a' && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
            ;

            const keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
                key: 'ArrowLeft',
                keyCode: 39,
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                shiftKey: false,
                ctrlKey: false,
                altKey: false,
                metaKey: false,
            });

            document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
        }
    });
})();
```